# Why does calling createSheet twice in a row corrupt doc in PHPExcel?

Tags: phpexcel

```
$workbook = new PHPExcel();
$workbook->createSheet()->setTitle('whatt')->setCellValue( 'A1', 'Another sheet' );
$workbook->createSheet()->setTitle('whatt')->setCellValue( 'A1', 'Another sheet' );
$objWriter = new PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007($workbook);
$objWriter->setOffice2003Compatibility(true);

ob_start();
$objWriter->save( "php://output" );
$contents = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();



// required for IE, otherwise Content-disposition is ignored
if(ini_get('zlib.output_compression'))
  ini_set('zlib.output_compression', 'Off');

$size = count($contents);

header("Pragma: public");
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Cache-Control: private",false);
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.msexcel; charset=utf-8');
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"test.xlsx\"");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
header("Content-Length: {$size}");
echo $contents;
exit;
```

When I download the sheet it comes down as 1 byte, with one sheet where the first cell is "P" ( because the file only contains that letter )
If I comment out the second `createSheet` line it works perfect. Any idea?

**EDIT**

I accepted the answer below which told me it wasn't PHPExcel's fault and it wasn't.
If I remove the headers and keep output buffering, as a test, it still works.

```
ob_start();
$objWriter->save( "php://output" );
$contents = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();

file_put_contents( "/mypath/uploads/test.xlsx", $contents );
```

I can download the file no problem. This leads me to believe the headers are screwing it up somehow, which is very bizarre considering there's no issue if I only used createSheet once. I guess I'll post that here when I figure it out.

....

And I figured out why the headers were messing it up. Apparently using `count($contents)` with one added sheet was fine, but with two added sheets it would only return `1`. I changed it to `strlen($contents)` and it worked. Bonus points if anyone can tell me why that happened :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No idea without a lot of debugging. Get rid of the redundant output buffering, and it works. This is the cause of your problem, nothing in PHPExcel.
So what are you doing subsequently with $contents?

Calling createSheet() twice in a row isn't corrupting anything: though why are you trying to create a workbook containing two worksheets with the same title anyway? PHPExcel will actually rename the second added worksheet as whatt2 to avoid problems.

Comment: Renaming both sheets doesn't change anything. I am buffering the output so I can get the size for the header before outputting and forcing a download of the info without saving to file system first. I will try removing the output buffer and saving to file system as a test.

Comment: Not using output buffer definitely made it work or headers. I don't want to save it to file system though so I'll have to figure out why that would break it. That's a whole other question so if I can't figure it out I'll post here. Either way you get the answer for this one :)